# Какие есть Gulp/Grunt модули для минификации css классов (напр., из .catalog__item в .a1)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, grunt

Нужно минифицировать через grunt или gulp имена css классов в html и css файлах. 
Например из .catalog__item и .catalog__titlie в .a1 и .a2. 
Тот редкий случай когда нужено именно это.

Единственное что нашел - [CSS Gsub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-gsub). Делает почти то, что нужно. Но не умеет работать с html-файлами.

[image]

Какие еще пакеты могут подойти?

Comment: не могли бы Вы пояснить цель такой *жесткой* минификации?

Comment: ТЗ клиента. Я прекрасно понимаю, что это не даст никакой защиты и особых выгод. И убедить клиента нельзя.
Так что рад любым советам по реализации этой задачи. Советы переубедить клиента принять не смогу.

Comment: ок. спасибо за пояснение.